# Pandas Groupby And Forward Fill Not Actually Filling

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of the following format:

| Store | Date | Payment Method | Attribute | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | cash | sales$ | 105 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | cash | items | 20 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | card | sales$ | 355 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | card | items | 50 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | cash | sales$ | NaN |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | cash | items | NaN |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | card | sales$ | 170 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | card | items | 35 |

I am trying to forward fill the NaNs, but grouped. For example, I don't want to fill the NaN sales$ with 50, the value above it. Rather, I want to fill the NaN sales$ with 105, the value for the previous cash-sales transaction at this store. To make this more difficult, I have multiple stores, and much more data (10+ million rows).

I tried:

```
df['Value'] = df.groupby(['Store','Payment Method','Attribute'])['Value'].ffill()
```

However, this did not replace any NaNs. It appears to have done nothing.

Any help is much appreciated.

The desired dataframe is below:

| Store | Date | Payment Method | Attribute | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | cash | sales$ | 105 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | cash | items | 20 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | card | sales$ | 355 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | card | items | 50 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | cash | sales$ | 105 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | cash | items | 20 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | card | sales$ | 170 |
| 5123 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | card | items | 35 |

Edit: I made this dataframe mockup (my real data is confidential, and when I asked the question I just did the mockup as a table here, not as code), and my initial attempt works. So I need to figure out why the exact same method doesn't work on my original dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [[5123, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'cash','sales$', 105],
        [5123, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'card','items', 20],
        [5123, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'cash','sales$', 355],
        [5123, '2021-01-01 00:00:00', 'card','items', 50],
        [5123, '2021-01-02 00:00:00', 'cash','sales$', np.nan],
        [5123, '2021-01-02 00:00:00', 'card','items', np.nan],
        [5123, '2021-01-02 00:00:00', 'cash','sales$', 170],
        [5123, '2021-01-02 00:00:00', 'card','items', 35]]

columns = ['Store', 'Date', 'Payment Method', 'Attribute', 'Value']

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = columns)
df['Value'] = df.groupby(['Store','Payment Method','Attribute'])['Value'].ffill()
```

Comment: Works on my side. Is it `NaN` the string `'NaN'` or `np.nan`?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes, df['Value'].isnull().values.any() returns True.

Comment: @edutt - Works for me too. What output are you getting?

Comment: @not_speshal I am just getting the initial dataframe, with the NaNs still there.

Comment: Can you isolate a single row that contains `NaN` (that's not getting filled) and include that in your above sample `df`? Use `df.head(10).to_dict()` for example.

Comment: @not_speshal Figured it out (duh). The first value for some of the groups in my real data is nan, so it's forward filling nan.

Comment: @edutt - Haha, gotcha. You need both `bfill` and `ffill` then. Something like `df.groupby(['Store','Payment Method','Attribute'])['Value'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())`

Comment: @not_speshal thank you - the NaN's in the initial few days of some of these stores are actually accurate (for example, if a store wasn't open yet, I do want to keep those NaN's). So I ended up just doing ffill, then fillna with zero for those initial NaN's. Much appreciate the help! Feel free to post an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: You solved this yourself. You should undelete your answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

My real data (not the mockup table here) had NaN values in some groups as the first value(s), due to the collection system starting up at different times for different stores. Therefore, for the first few replacements that ffill did, it forward filled that nan value into the following nan values. This is the correct behavior. I ran the ffill code in my question, then filled NaN with zero where forward fill did not fill a non-null value, and I have the result I wanted.